# Should I deploy Firebase Cloud Messaging server myself?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've read the document about FCM, but I wonder if I should deploy a FCM server myself. Does the google cloud platform not provide FCM server? Or do I must implemented my own FCM server refering to the official reference implementation, [gcm-playgroud](https://github.com/googlesamples/gcm-playground)?

Comment: See this page in the documentation describing the two [servers involved in sending cloud messages with Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends. (How's that for an answer?)

By "server", I'm assuming you mean, "Code I will be running on the server level to communicate with the FCM service". And honestly, the answer depends on whether or not you need extra functionality that's not supplied by the Firebase Notifications panel.

You can do a lot with Firebase Notifications, including sending scheduled messages, or sending messages to individual users, topics, or Audiences. But that is work that is done manually. If you just want to send the occasional promotional message to your users, you shouldn't need a server.

On the other hand, maybe you've got a messaging app and you want to send a notification to your user anytime they receive a new message. Well, that's clearly something that needs to be automated, and that requires some server-side code. So for that, you will need to set up your own server that communicates with FCM.